# Merge multiple dictionaries conditionally

Tags: python, dictionary

I have N dictionaries that contain the same keys, with values that are integers. I want to merge these into a single dictionary based on the maximum value. Currently I have something like this:

```
max_dict = {}
for dict in original_dict_list:
    for key, val in dict.iteritems():
        if key not in max_dict or max_dict[key] < val:
            max_dict[key] = val
```

Is there a better (or more "pythonic") way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`collection.Counter()` objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead, they support 'merging' counts natively:

```
from collections import Counter

max_dict = Counter()
for d in original_dict_list:
    max_dict |= Counter(d)
```

or even:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import or_

max_dict = reduce(or_, map(Counter, original_dict_list))
```

`Counter` objects are multi-sets (also called 'bags' sometimes). The `|` operator performs a union on two counters, storing the maximum count for a given key.

A `Counter` is also a straight subclass of `dict`, so you can (mostly) treat it like any other dictionary.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from operator import or_
>>> original_dict_list = [{'foo': 3, 'bar': 10}, {'foo': 42, 'spam': 20}, {'bar': 5, 'ham': 10}]
>>> reduce(or_, map(Counter, original_dict_list))
Counter({'foo': 42, 'spam': 20, 'bar': 10, 'ham': 10})
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming not all dictionaries contain all keys:

```
keys = set(k for x in original_dict_list for k in x)
max_dict = {k:max([x[k] for x in original_dict_list if k in x]) for k in keys}
```

Comment: In this particular instance, you could use `x[k]` instead of `x.get(k,-1)`, because the dictionaries all use the same keys. If they didn't, though, I'd suggest replacing your innermost list comprehension with `[x[k] for x in original_dict_list if k in x]`

Answer (score 0):

```
max_dict = { k:max([v]+[ _dict[k] for _dict in original_dict_list[1:] ])
             for k,v in original_dict_list[0].items() }
```